# ourDatabase is null?

Tags: android, android-studio

Ok, so I'm getting a nullpointerexception error in SQLDatabase.java (shown at the end of this post) on ourDatabase at 216. The MusicCenter.java is an activity and it's supposed to search an ArrayList and insert the artist, song title, and its lyrics into a database (will use later), but instead it crashes and the logcat says:

Still in-need of help. Please someone

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pip8O.png

Song.java:

```
package com.musicplayer;

import android.os.StrictMode;

import com.lyricscloud.SQLDatabase;


import com.lyricscloud.Websites;

public class Song {

public Song(long songID, String songTitle, String songArtist) {
    id=songID;
    title=songTitle;
    artist=songArtist;
    generateLyricsFunc(artist,title);
    if(Lyrics!=null && !Lyrics.equals("")) {
        SQLDatabase db = new SQLDatabase(MusicCenter.c);
        db.createEntry(artist, title, Lyrics, "Songs");--Error here
        db.close();
    }
}
  public long getID(){return id;}
  public String getTitle(){return title;}
  public String getLyrics(){return Lyrics;}
  public String getArtist(){return artist;}
}
```

MusicCenter.java:

```
        getSongList();
        for(int i=0; i<songsAmnt;i++) {
            SQLDatabase db = new SQLDatabase(this);
            db.open();
            db.createEntry(songList.get(i).getArtist(),songList.get(i).getTitle(),songList.get(i).getLyrics(),"Song");
            db.close();
        }
```

getSongList method:

```
  public static void getSongList() {
    ContentResolver musicResolver = c.getContentResolver();
    Uri musicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);
    if (musicCursor != null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
        int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
        int artistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
        do {
            long thisId = musicCursor.getLong(idColumn);
            String thisTitle = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);
            String thisArtist = musicCursor.getString(artistColumn);
            if(!thisArtist.equals("<unknown>") && !thisArtist.equals("Facebook")) {
                Log.d(CompName,"Id:" + thisId + " Title:" + thisTitle + " Artist: " + thisArtist);
                songList.add(new Song(thisId, thisTitle, thisArtist)); //error here
                songsAmnt =+ 1;
            }
        }
        while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
        musicCursor.close();
    }
}
```

SQLDatabase.java:

```
package com.lyricscloud;

import android.content.ContentValues;

import android.content.Context;

import android.database.Cursor;

import android.database.SQLException;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import android.util.Log;   
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SQLDatabase {

public static final String SONGKEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String SONGKEY_ARTISTNAME = "artist_name";
public static final String SONGKEY_SONGNAME = "song_name";
public static final String SONGKEY_LYRICS = "lyrics";
public static final String[] SONGALL_KEYS = new String[]{SONGKEY_ROWID, SONGKEY_ARTISTNAME, SONGKEY_SONGNAME, SONGKEY_LYRICS};


private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "LyricsCloudDB";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "BookmarkTable";
private static final String bookMarksTable = "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
        KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        KEY_ARTISTNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
        KEY_SONGNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
        KEY_LYRICS + " TEXT NOT NULL);";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;
private static SQLDatabase instance = null;

private DbHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE_SONGS = "SongsTable";
private static final String songsTable = "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE_SONGS + " (" +
        SONGKEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        SONGKEY_ARTISTNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
        SONGKEY_SONGNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
        SONGKEY_LYRICS + " TEXT NOT NULL);";

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        db.execSQL(songsTable);

        db.execSQL(bookMarksTable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST " + DATABASE_TABLE_SONGS);
        onCreate(db);

    }
}


public SQLDatabase(Context c) {
    ourContext = c;

}

boolean isTableExists(SQLiteDatabase db, String tableName)
{
    if (tableName == null || db == null || !db.isOpen())
    {
        return false;
    }
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = ? AND name = ?", new String[] {"table", tableName});
    if (!cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        return false;
    }
    int count = cursor.getInt(0);
    cursor.close();
    return count > 0;
}

public long createEntry(String artistname, String songname, String lyrics, String which) {
        if(which.equals("Bookmark")) {
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(KEY_ARTISTNAME, artistname);
            cv.put(KEY_SONGNAME, songname);
            cv.put(KEY_LYRICS, lyrics);
            return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
        }else{
            try {
                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                cv.put(KEY_ARTISTNAME, artistname);
                cv.put(KEY_SONGNAME, songname);
                if(lyrics!=null && !lyrics.equals("")) {
                    cv.put(KEY_LYRICS, lyrics);
                    Log.d("DataBaseShit","Lyrics is not null");
                }
                if(isTableExists(ourDatabase,songsTable)){
                    Log.d("DataBaseShit","Test");
                }else{
                    Log.d("DataBaseShit","Table not created");
                    ourDatabase.execSQL(DATABASE_TABLE_SONGS); --Get's an error here
                    if(isTableExists(ourDatabase,songsTable)){
                        Log.d("DataBaseShit","Test");
                    }else{
                        Log.d("DataBaseShit","Table not credated");
                    }
                }
                //Log.d("DataBaseShit", "Artist: " + artistname + " Song:" + songname + " Lyrics:" + lyrics);
                return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_SONGS, null, cv); --if I remove ourDatabase.execSQL line above then the error moves to this line.
            }catch(NullPointerException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    return 0;
}

}
```

Comment: It would help if you could include line numbers, or at least point out the spot the error is pointing to.  It would also help to include the code for "ourDatabase" unless you are referring to SQLDatabase.java.  If you can also trim out any unnecessary code from the post, this will help others to answer your question as well.

Comment: Jonathan, I am referring to SQLDatabase.java and I'm sorry about the excess amount of code, I've posted in the past and had people complain that they'd like to see the full code, I have edited my question and took out some code, but I'm afraid to take out to much because I'm not sure what will be needed and is not needed. I'm not even sure how this log cat output even came to. I have also marked where it is giving errors in Song.java, SQLDatabase.java, and MusicCenter.java

Answer (score 0):

You should give a SQL Query in this below line parenthesis,

```
ourDatabase.execSQL(DATABASE_TABLE_SONGS);
```

But as per your initiations `DATABASE_TABLE_SONGS = "SongsTable";` which is the table name and not the query to create the table. You have to **change** that line to

```
ourDatabase.execSQL(songsTable);
```

`songsTable` is the variable which you have actually initiated with the query to create the Table.

And when you comment the above line, the error will obviously go to that insert line, as there you will be trying to insert data into a table that is not created. The above line is actually used to create the `SongsTable`

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for correcting me, I already created the table in the onCreate but was seeing if would make the table if I added that line and that when I noticed ourDatabase was null.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialized `ourDatabase`. Call `getWritableDatabase()` on the open helper to init it before calling any methods on it:

```
ourDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
```

Comment: I have initialized it, not to be rude but if you look at Jonathan's comment on my post he said there was too much code, so I deleted the initialization of ourDatabase and ourHelper